# How to add string to sitemap.xml before </urlset> closing tag, in php

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

after hours of looking for solution, i could not find any that works or suits my issue.

Basically, i have dynamic website, that generates new pages and i want to add to it the ability to add that new page to the sitemap.xml

When i use the :

```
file_put_contents("$sitemap_file", $string_to_add, FILE_APPEND);
```

it will add the `$string_to_add` at the end of the sitemap.xml, after the /urlset tag.

Is there any way to add this string before the /urlset tag ?

My code at the moment :

```
$date_mod = date('Y-m-d');
$string = "
<url>
    <loc>https://www.mywebsite.com$internal_link</loc>
    <lastmod>$date_mod</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>";

file_put_contents("$root/sitemap.xml", $string, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Yes, by using xml parser instead.

Comment: Without xml parser you have to do it in two steps. 1. remove `</urlset>` using `str_replace`, 2. add `$string . '</urlset>'`.

Comment: If any of the provided solution was helpful, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like below using [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$date_mod = date('Y-m-d');
$string = "
<url>
    <loc>https://www.mywebsite.com$internal_link</loc>
    <lastmod>$date_mod</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>";


$xml = simplexml_load_file("$root/sitemap.xml");
$xml->addChild($string);

file_put_contents("$root/sitemap.xml", $xml->asXML());
```

This will put `<url>` inside `<urlset>` tag, hopefully.

Comment: Works good, but it adds an "/&gt" which i suppose it's not a problem, and also between the strings it adds an extra "<" which i just removed from the string text to compensate :
 
</url>/&gt;<url>
  <loc>test3</loc>
  <lastmod>date</lastmod>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
 </url>/&gt;<url>
  <loc>test3</loc>
  <lastmod>date</lastmod>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
 </url>/>

Comment: Yes, this was just to give an example, you should follow the link to [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), and learn more about it. You will definetely have to tweek this code a bit to your requirements.

Comment: ty so very much

Comment: If the solution was helpful. Please, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SimpleXML:

```
// You can also do
// $xmlStr= file_get_contents('sitemap.xml');
$xmlStr=<<<XML
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://domain.fake/link1.html</loc>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://domain.fake/link2.html</loc>
<priority>0.99</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
XML;

// Create the SimpleXML object from the string
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
// add an <url> child to the <urlset> node
$url = $xml->addChild("url");
// add the <loc> and <priority> children to the <url> node 
$url->addChild("loc", "http://domain.fake/link2.html");
$url->addChild("priority", 0.98);

// get the updated XML string
$newXMLStr = $xml->asXML();
//write it to the sitemap.xml file
file_put_contents('sitemap.xml',$newXMLStr);
```